# QTreeWidgetItem data

Tags: c++, qt

I have a following data:

```
1.0 2.0 3.1 4.1 5.2
```

Where Index.SubIndex
But I want to show in `QTreeWidget` as following:
**Index 1**
     Index 3
     Index 4
**Index 2**
     Index 5

But I did as following:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *child = new QTreeWidgetItem();
child->setText("Index " + QString::number(index));
```

But I want to save hidden data, which I should to get when user selected any item of tree.
How I can do this? Which signal/slot I can use for it? I mean I should get not "Index 1" or "Index 2" and etc, I should get 1,2,3,4,5,6 aand etc. And parse text is NOT solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand half of your question. But for storing custom data in a QTreeWidgetItem I would subclass it:

```
class my_tree_item : public QTreeWidgetItem
{
    public:        
        my_tree_item(custom_data* d, QString& str) { this->dat=d; QTreeWidgetItem(str); }
        ~my_tree_item();

        inline custom_data* get_data { return this->dat; }

    private:
        custom_data* dat;
};
```

If you then receive a QTreeWidgetItem from a signal you can simply retrieve the data

```
custom_data* c = static_cast<my_tree_item*>(some_qtreewidgetitem)->get_data();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Qt::UserRole` data field to store your custom data and retrieve it when a QTreeItemWidget is selected:

```cpp
QTreeWidgetItem* child = new QTreeWidgetItem();
child->setText(0, "Index " + QString::number(index));
// save internal data to retrieve later on
child->setData(0, Qt::UserRole, QVariant(index));
```